# Post from external site to MVC controller that has typed parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new to MVC so I was struggling with the title of the question -- not sure if there's anything already covering what I want to do.

Suppose I have a controller: FooController.  It handles a set of views, all of which do the same basic thing, but use different models for various reasons.  So I create an action for each model, and this works well:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Bar(Type1 t);
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Bar(Type2 t);
```

etc...

What I want to accomplish (if possible) is to create an action that can accept a POST from a 3rd party website (in addition to the typed-views locally) and I can't seem to figure out how to accept the data without MVC throwing an exception:

> The current request for action 'Bar' on controller type 'FooController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:

And it lists the above actions.

I've tried a couple things:

- Created a method Bar(ExternalSiteType t) - Exception
- Created a method Bar(ExternalSiteParam1 p, ExternalSiteParam2 p2) - Exception
- Commented out the other actions - Success for both methods above

Any ideas how to get this to work?

EDIT: Route examples

/Foo/Bar/Type1

/Foo/Bar/Type2

/Foo/Bar/ExternalSite

Comment: Could you post example route  values (url address to get the controller)?

Comment: You cannot have the same action name for two action methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Bar(Type1 t);
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Bar(Type2 t);
```

could work at all, even if it was from the same site. You can't have two actions with the same name unless they use different Http verbs (`[HttpGet],[HttpPost]` etc).

Your best best would be to create an action with a different name for the external site, convert the passed in information to `Type1` and then Redirect to `Bar(Type1 t)`. See [ASP.NET MVC Redirect with model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013695/asp-net-mvc-redirect-with-model) for different ways you could Redirect and preserve your complex object.

Comment: Hmm. I guess that would explain it then. Thanks.